# how to get tag of focused content after drag finger from another

Tags: android

I want to implement something like this 
[Requirement-Image](http://highonandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/how-to-add-pie-control-to-any-rooted-android-smartphone-tablet-lmt-launcher-app-13-690x459.jpg)

[Video_Requirement-1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUKOsq2Bhi0)

[Video_Requirement-2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80KhR94n_Ss)

You can install this application to know about actual requirement
[Functionality](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jun.ace.piecontrol&hl=en)

I need to handle a situation below :

1.) I have an open button, see image number-1
2.) On key down(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP of onTouch()), the two more buttons in a semicircle shown as in image number-2
3.) After put finger on open button, I drag my finger to new inflated buttons without remove my finger from screen(i.e. drag the finger to the new buttons), and on which button i drag my finger, being highlighted.
4.) How to perform a new task on behalf of on which button(new inflate) I have the focus.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: as far as i know, thats not possible. The only way would be to set the onTouchListener on the underlaying view and check manually if the finger is over one of the zones.

Comment: The shaded view displays on click, but I am searching like hover effect  in web technology, as the cursor moves on! Here I need to get the tag of the view(content), as user touch content say "X" , & drag his finger to content "Y" without move up.